# URI of MySQL for SQLAlchemy for connection without password

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Could someone kindly advise how the uri of MySQL for SQLAlchemy for a connection without password should be set?

For the code as below, the pymysql part works, but the SQLAlchemy has the below error.  I have tried other uri as well as commented below, all failed.

The database name is "finance_fdata_master"

Thanks a lot

```
# Using pymysql

import pymysql
dbcon = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', database='finance_fdata_master')


# Using SQLAlchemy

from os import environ
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

uri = 'mysql+pymysql://root@localhost/finance_fdata_master'

db_uri = environ.get(uri)
engine = create_engine(db_uri, echo=True)

# uri = 'pymysql://root@localhost:3306/finance_fdata_master'
# uri = r'mysql://root@127.0.0.1:3306/finance_fdata_master'
# uri = r'mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/finance_fdata_master'
# uri = r'mysql://root@localhost/finance_fdata_master'
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File C:\PythonProjects\TradeAnalysis\Test\TestSQLAlchemy.py:23 in <module>
    engine = create_engine(db_uri, echo=True)

  File <string>:2 in create_engine

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py:309 in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py:532 in create_engine
    u, plugins, kwargs = u._instantiate_plugins(kwargs)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'
```

Comment: Blank password or no password has been setup for the myself server. After all it is just at localhost for personal use
And everything is under Windows, not unix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code defines a connection URL string in the variable `uri`. Then you look up an environment variable with that name and it doesn't exist, so `db_uri` is `None`. Then you pass that (`None` value) to `create_engine()` and it fails.

```py
engine = create_engine(uri, echo=True)  # not db_uri
```

will probably work better.

Comment: you are right.  I was blindly following the sample code in https://hackersandslackers.com/connecting-pandas-to-a-sql-database-with-sqlalchemy/  without carefully thinking what does the environ in there do.  Thanks a lot